# jQuery 1.6.2 bind no longer functioning with drag events?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.6

I am trying to use `.bind()` with `'dragenter'`, `'dragover'`, and `'drop'` so I can drag a file from my desktop to my browser.

Please see attached jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/v82An/23/

```
$(function(){
    function dragenter(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    function dragover(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    }    
    function drop(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();        
        alert('hi')
    }

    $('#drop').bind('dragenter', dragenter, false);
    $('#drop').bind('dragover', dragover, false);
    $('#drop').bind('drop', drop, false);    
});
```

This fiddle attaches these events properly in 1.5, but in 1.6 they simply don't work.

Anyone know if I'm just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to work if you don't set `preventBubble` to `false`:

```
$('#drop').bind('dragenter', dragenter);
$('#drop').bind('dragover', dragover);
$('#drop').bind('drop', drop);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/v82An/24/)

**Update:** If you look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), passing three parameters where the last one is a boolean, is interpreted as:

```
.bind( eventType, [eventData], preventBubble )
```

which means that the handler is not used as event handler but as event data.

They changed how they detect the handler though. In [jQuery 1.5.2](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.5.2/src/event.js#L912), it was:

```
if ( jQuery.isFunction( data ) || data === false ) {
    fn = data;
    data = undefined;
}
```

You see, when the second argument was a function, then this one was used as event handler (instead of the third one).

But it was changed in [jQuery 1.6.2](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/event.js#L906) to:

```
if ( arguments.length === 2 || data === false ) {
    fn = data;
    data = undefined;
}
```

Now it is only tested how many arguments are passed. As, in your case, `data` is not `false` (it is a function) and you pass three arguments, `fn` is not changed. It stays `false`.

When the handler is `false`, [then this happens](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.2/src/event.js#L26):

```
if ( handler === false ) {
    handler = returnFalse;
} else if ( !handler ) {
    // Fixes bug #7229. Fix recommended by jdalton
    return;
}
```

So this could actually be seen as bug in jQuery 1.5 which is now fixed and is not a problem with these particular events.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my issue lied with jQuery glorifying the original event object during the bind process.

My code looked like this:

```
$dropArea = $(".dropArea");
$dropArea.bind({
    dragover: function (ev) {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        ev.preventDefault();
        return false;
    },
    dragend: function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        return false;
    },
    dragleave: function () {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
        return false;
    },
    drop: function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        //e = e || window.event;
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

        console.log("dropping element.");
        return false;
    });
```

jQuery was wrapping the old event object up into a newer more glorified jQuery version of the event object.

I added this line:

```
ev = ev.originalEvent;
```

to get the original event object back, upon which I could call the preventDefault(), and all worked well once again.

I hope this helps save someone time!  (Still wrapping my head around the jQuery objects and functions associated with them, as they relate back to the original javascript objects).